# Possible PHP Bug? Array assignment with simple subtraction

Tags: php, arrays

I am stumbled upon a very frustrating problem where the following two lines of code (in a loop iterating in months) are giving different results (last one is wrong)

SO.. this line give a good result

```
echo $product[$pData['product_sku']][$rollMonthKey] - $rollingSubtractionTotal;
Outputs:
Aug 2014: -218
Sep 2014: 50
Oct 2014: 268
Nov 2014: 436
Dec 2014: 554
```

But this one doesn't... I need to store the value as below and not echo it (saved to xlsx file later)

```
$product[$pData['product_sku']][$rollMonthKey] -= $rollingSubtractionTotal;
echo $product[$pData['product_sku']][$rollMonthKey];
Outputs:
Aug 2014: -218
Sep 2014: 50
Oct 2014: 50
Nov 2014: 50
Dec 2014: 50
```

Can someone please shed some light? (This is not common PHP behavior)

All the loop/code below...

```
  foreach ($product as $sku => $pData) {


  // forecast/sales deduction part
  for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {

    if($m >= $thismonth){

      $rollMonthKey = date('F Y',strtotime($thisyear.'-'.$m.'-01'));

      $rollingSubtractionTotal = 0;

      for($rm=0;$rm<=$m-$thismonth;$rm++){
        $rollMonthKeyCalc = date('F Y',strtotime($thisyear.'-'.$m.'-01 -'.($rm+1).' Month'));
        $rollingSubtractionTotal += $product[$pData['product_sku']][$rollMonthKeyCalc];
      }

      $product[$pData['product_sku']][$rollMonthKey] -= $rollingSubtractionTotal;

      echo '<br />';

    }

  }
  exit;
```

Comment: Can you share more code? Like the loop itself?

Comment: You're not looping with $pData by reference are you?

Comment: puelo: added the loop/code above
Mark: Let me add the foreach before the for loop... 5sec

Comment: added the foreach part... I am altering the array while in the foreach

Comment: PS: I am not looping by reference.. although my problem seems to be similar to this
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem was to use the Value of the foreach loop rather then over complicating stuff using the main data array... the fix required just 2 lines changed...

```
      for($rm=0;$rm<=$m-$thismonth;$rm++){
        $rollMonthKeyCalc = date('F Y',strtotime($thisyear.'-'.$m.'-01 -'.($rm+1).' Month'));

        /* changed line */
        $rollingSubtractionTotal += $pData[$rollMonthKeyCalc];
      }

      /* changed line */
      $product[$sku][$rollMonthKey] -= $rollingSubtractionTotal;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$rollingSubtractionTotal = 50;
```

After August you're telling php that your value of `$product[$pData['product_sku']][$rollMonthKey];` should = 50;

In your first statement you minus 50 from `$product[$pData['product_sku']][$rollMonthKey];`
In your second you assign 50, It can't decrement as your key value isn't fixed.